# Getting the key value from a JSON object

Tags: c#, json

I am passing an object to a C# `winform` application via `socketIO` i manage to get the data, but having trouble getting the key value from the object, so far below is my code to capture the data from the socket server.

```
socket.On("traverseLeft", (data) =>
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {

           MessageBox.Show(data.ToString());

        }));

    });
```

So my output is below, what I need to get is the interactive_link's value which is "sub", how can I achieve this on C#?

```
{  
   "msg":{  
      "interactive_link":"sub"
   }
}
```

Comment: you should use newtonsoft to parse json. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json
check their site for code samples

Comment: just search for any way of parsing json in C#... there are many ways and many examples

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `JObject` to read the properties

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
Console.WriteLine(obj["msg"]["interactive_link"]);
```

Comment: This is the most simple approach to get the data, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

First, download the Newtonsoft NuGet package: `Newtonsoft.Json` from NuGet.

Then create the following classes:

```cs
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("msg")]
    public Message Message { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    [JsonProperty("interactive_link")]
    public string InteractiveLink { get; set; }
}
```

And finally do this:

```cs
var inputObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);
var message = inputObj.Message.InteractiveLink;
MessageBox.Show(message);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the model class as per your JSON response. You can create it online using http://json2csharp.com/

```
public class Msg
{
    public string interactive_link { get; set; }
}

public class MyJson
{
    public Msg msg { get; set; }
}
```

And then deserialize your json to this class using `Newtonsoft.Json`([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)).

```
var myJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyJson>(json);
```

And then access your data

```
var interactiveLink = myJson.msg.interactive_link;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data has a defined structure, you can use a Strongly-Typed manner. So you should define your classes first:

```
public class Msg
{
    public string interactive_link { get; set; }
}

public class DataObject
{
    public Msg msg { get; set; }
}
```

And the parse your JSON result to the defined object:

```
var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataObject>(data);
```